# how to set height and width to image uploaded using setImageValue in phpword?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpword

I am using this code and it is uploading the image to the docx it functions well,
but the problem the size of the image is too small I need to increase the height and width

$templateProcessor->setImageValue('image',[$image_path,['width' => 40,
            'height' => 40]]);
it is not working 
is it even possible?

```
    $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(asset('docx/job_application.docx'));
    $templateProcessor->setImageValue('image',$image_path);
    $templateProcessor->saveAs('docx/'.$file_name.'.docx');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template, set the bookmark to $[image:450:334}

Comment: The numbers in my example are generic.  If you wanted 40, it's be ${image:40:40}

Answer (score 0):

$templateProcessor->setImageValue('image',['path'=>$image_path, 'width' => 40, 'height' => 40])

Answer (score -1):

see https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#setimagevalue

```
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('image', [
  'path' => $image_path,
  'width' => 600,
  'height' => 400,
]);
```

Comment: Please be more complete in your answers, provide some explanation.